# Rails select in scope with virtual attribute returns an empty ActiveRecord Relation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In a Rails 4.1.2 app with MySQL I'm doing the following:

```
scope :popular, -> {
  select("images.*, SUM(likes_count + comments_count + reposts_count) as score").
  where("DATE(created_at) > DATE(?)", 4.weeks.ago).
  order('score DESC')
}
```

to get a recent set of "popular" images. The problem is that if there are no images that match this query, I get an `ActiveRecord::Relation` with all nil values, e.g...

`#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Image id: nil, user_id: nil, image_uid: nil, image_name: nil>]>`

This is causing problems as the collection is not empty. How would I get that scope to return 'nil' if no results, or just reject if the object is empty or something?

**UPDATE**

```
Image.popular.select {|i| i.id.present? }
```

kinda solves the problem, but to me this seems more like a workaround than a solution...

Comment: scope will always return `AR`, and you can test it by using `#blank?` or `#present?` ...

Comment: blank? returns false, present? returns true - as I said the collection is not empty so this doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

You could make sure you're not returning anything with a `nil` value for `id`. Perhaps something like:

```
scope :popular, -> {
  select("images.*, SUM(likes_count + comments_count + reposts_count) as score").
  where("DATE(created_at) > DATE(?) AND id IS NOT NULL", 4.weeks.ago).
  order('score DESC')
}
```

**EDIT**

An alternative approach would be to simplify your query by caching the `score` attribute on the model. Generate a migration and add your attribute to your model. Then, use a `before_save` callback:

```
before_save :cache_score

def cache_score
  self.score = likes_count + comments_count + reposts_count
end
```

Then you could make your query simpler:

```
scope :popular, -> { where("created_at > ?", 4.weeks.ago).order('score DESC') }
```